# Check for sufficiency

Tags: statistics

We have the function

$$f(x) = \frac{1}{2x\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{(\ln x - \theta)^2}{8}}$$ for the I.I.D (identically independent distributed) sample $X_1,\dots, X_n$.

I have to show that $\sum_{i=1}^n{ln X_i}$ is a sufficient statistic.

My approach was to take the product of the pdf and then to split the product up in two parts, one with the sufficient statistic and $\theta$ and the second part containing $X_1,\dots, X_n$.

But for me it's an impossible task to split the product up and find the sufficient statistic, if someone could help, that would be great!

Comment: You should really show your work, wrer are you stuck? One hint: the range of the argument $x$ is obviously $0<x<\infty$. I am sure that was stated in the problem! but you left it out. Think about that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, for better understanding how to find the sufficient statistic one cat see [this](https://onlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat414/node/284) very nice lecture.
Anyway, you can start with the joint probability density function of $\vec{X}=(X_1,\dots,X_n)$. So it will be $$f_{\vec{X}}(x_1\ldots x_n)=\prod_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{2x_i\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{(\ln x_i - \theta)^2}{8}}=\prod_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\ln (x_i)}e^{-\frac{(\ln( x_i) - \theta)^2}{8}}$$
$$f_{\vec{X}}(x_1\ldots x_n)=\left(\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2\pi}}\right)^n e^{-\sum_{i=1}^n\left(\ln (x_i)+ \frac{(\ln( x_i) - \theta)^2}{8}\right)}$$
Expanding the power one can obtain:
$$f_{\vec{X}}(x_1\ldots x_n)=\left(\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2\pi}}\right)^n e^{-\sum_{i=1}^n\left(\ln (x_i)+ \frac{\ln^2( x_i)}{8}-\frac{\ln(x_i)\theta}{4}+\frac{\theta^2}{8}\right)}$$
Or
$$f_{\vec{X}}(x_1\ldots x_n)=\left(\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2\pi}}\right)^n e^{\sum_{i=1}^n\left(-\frac{\ln^2( x_i)}{8} +\ln (x_i)\left(\frac{\theta}{4}-1\right)-\frac{\theta^2}{8}\right)}$$ 
By the way one can omit two last steps. The sufficient statistic can be obtained from the second step.
Then one can rewrite it in the following manner:
$$f_{\vec{X}}(x_1\ldots x_n)=\left(\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2\pi}}\right)^n e^{-\sum_{i=1}^n \left(\frac{\ln^2( x_i)}{8}+\ln( x_i)\right)}e^{-\frac{n\theta^2}{8}}e^{\frac{1}{4}\theta\sum_{i=1}^n \ln(x_i)}$$
According to [the Fisher–Neyman factorization theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sufficient_statistic):

"If the probability density function is $f_\theta(x)$, then $T$ is sufficient for $\theta$ if and only if nonnegative functions $g$ and $h$ can be found such that $f_\theta(x)=h(x) \, g_\theta(T(x))$".

So in the power of the last multiplier the parameter $\theta$ depends on the sample $\vec{X}$ only in terms of statistics $T=\sum_{i=1}^n \ln(x_i)$.

Comment: @cruise thanks :)

Comment: @Caran-dAche I think you're missing a '$2$' though in the third step. I think it should be $\left(\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2\pi}}\right)^n$. Furthermore, there is a superfluous bracket in front of  the $\frac{\ln^2x_i}{8}$ in the power there I think.

Comment: @cruise ahhh... my bad. Poor eyesight. I'll fix it.

Comment: Hahah happens to the best ;). Maybe I'm just in an overly critical mood :P.

Answer (score 2):

Your random variable $X$ has pdf $f(x; \theta)$:

[image]
<sub>(source: [tri.org.au](http://www.tri.org.au/se/lognormalpdf.png))</sub>

The joint density of $\overset{\rightharpoonup }{X}=\left(X_1,\ldots ,X_i,\ldots ,X_n\right)$, a random sample of size $n$ on $X$, is given by:

$$f_* \left(\overset{\rightharpoonup }{x};\theta \right)=\prod _{i=1}^n f \left(x_i;\theta \right)$$

The mathStatica function `Sufficient` constructs the joint density $f_* \left(\overset{\rightharpoonup }{x};\theta \right)$, and then simplifies it. The output from `Sufficient` can be useful when attempting to identify sufficient statistics for a parameter. For your example, we get:

[image]
<sub>(source: [tri.org.au](http://www.tri.org.au/se/sufficientlognorm.png))</sub>

From this, it is easy to see that if we define $S=\sum _{i=1}^n \log  X_i$, we can construct :

$$f_* \left(\overset{\rightharpoonup }{x};\theta \right) = g(s;\theta) h(\vec x) $$

where $g(s;\theta)$  a non-negative function (not necessarily a density function), and $h(\vec x)$ a non-negative function that does not involve $\theta$. In particular, take:

$$g(s;\theta) = e^{\frac{1}{8} \left(2 \theta  s-\theta ^2 n\right)}$$

and

$$h(\vec x)=2^{-\frac{3 n}{2}} \pi ^{-\frac{n}{2}} e^{-\frac{1}{8} \sum _{i=1}^n \log ^2\left(x_i\right)} \prod _{i=1}^n \frac{1}{x_i} $$

Then, by the Factorisation Criterion, $S$ is a sufficient statistic for $\theta$.